# How can I get this hittest to work

Tags: hittest

I'm creating a game where you as the player is holding a baseball bat and when you click the button you swing your bat. When you swing your bat you hit the enemy the enemy goes flying off in the opposite direction of where you hit them like a golf ball. I have done the moving and attacking function working but how can I register the hittest so it hits the enemy when facing towards it and the enemy going back. This is what I done so far:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Player extends MovieClip
    {
        var walkSpeed:Number = 4;
        var walkRight:Boolean = false;
        var walkLeft:Boolean = false;
        var walkUp:Boolean = false;
        var walkDown:Boolean = false;
        var attacking:Boolean = false;

        public function Player()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN , walk);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Update);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, stopWalk);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, attack);
        }

        function walk(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {

            if (event.keyCode == 68)
            {
                walkRight = true;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 87)
            {
                walkUp = true;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 65)
            {
                walkLeft = true;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 83)
            {
                walkDown = true;
            }
        }

        function Update(event:Event)
        {
            if (attacking == true)
            {
                walkRight = false;
                walkLeft = false;
                walkUp = false;
                walkDown = false;
            }
            else if (attacking == false)
            {
                var dx = parent.mouseX - x;
                var dy = parent.mouseY - y;
                var angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx) / Math.PI * 180;
                rotation = angle;

                if (walkRight == true)
                {
                    x +=  walkSpeed;
                    gotoAndStop('walk');
                }
                if (walkUp == true)
                {
                    y -=  walkSpeed;
                    gotoAndStop('walk');
                }
                if (walkLeft == true)
                {
                    x -=  walkSpeed;
                    gotoAndStop('walk');
                }
                if (walkDown == true)
                {
                    y +=  walkSpeed;
                    gotoAndStop('walk');
                }
            }


        }

        function stopWalk(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            if (attacking == false)
            {
                if (event.keyCode == 68)
                {
                    event.keyCode = 0;
                    walkRight = false;
                    gotoAndStop('stance');
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 87)
                {
                    event.keyCode = 0;
                    walkUp = false;
                    gotoAndStop('stance');
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 65)
                {
                    event.keyCode = 0;
                    walkLeft = false;
                    gotoAndStop('stance');
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 83)
                {
                    event.keyCode = 0;
                    walkDown = false;
                    gotoAndStop('stance');
                }
            }
        }

        function attack(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            if (attacking == false)
            {
                attacking = true;
                gotoAndStop('attack');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the character's direction changes, change a variable depending on the way they are now facing, for example; direction = 0 when they are facing down, 1 when they are facing right, etc. Then use this and the enemy's position to work out whether or not the enemy has been hit. For making the enemy fly back, you would get the character's direction to work out which way they would fly back. I would give some example code to help explain, but I'm on my tablet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I was thinking it of doing it like this, I should see if the zombie is close enough to be hit by the bat (using the bat's length as the circle radius) and if the angle between the direction of the character and the line to the zombie is within a swipe range, then they hit. So, if the angle to the zombie if + or - 15 degrees from the way the player is facing, for example, they are in swipe territory.I wanted to see were there any other easier way.

Comment: so far I was able calculate the radius but how can I get the angle correct so they are in the hit area                                  public var angle:Number = 0;                                            public var radius:Number = 95;                                          var rad:Number = angle * (Math.PI / 180);
MovieClip(root).Zombie.x = x + radius * Math.cos(rad);
MovieClip(root).Zombie.y = y + radius * Math.sin(rad);

Comment: I didn't realise you wanted to make it so precise. I'm afraid I can't help you with that, as I have not yet needed to do those sort of calculations. Sorry.